# Weird problem with L'Hopital's rule: $\lim\limits_{x\to 0^-} x^3e^{1/x}$

Tags: calculus, limits, infinity

$$\lim\limits_{x\to 0^-} x^3e^{1/x}$$

If I plug in zero, I get $0\cdot\infty$. So, this, I thought was a hint to try to rewrite the problem to try to get $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ or $\frac{0}{0} so that I could apply L'Hôpital's.

Once I did this and applied L'Hôpital's, I still kept getting $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$.

*** Then, someone in my class pointed out that $$\lim_{x\to 0^-} e^{1/x}=0$$
I checked on the calculator and verified this. But, then, why is it that when you plug in $0$ you get $e^{\infty}$ which is infinity? 
If I were to run into this question on a test where no calculator was allowed, I would've thought this to be $e^{\infty}$. Can someone explain this?

***Omg I think I just found out the answer to my own question....(well actually, Google helped me) but I just want to make sure...is it because you're plugging in NEGATIVE very small numbers into x...so then it would be $e^{-\infty}$ which is basically zero. Yes or no?

Comment: Yes. If $x$ is negative and close to $0$, then $e^{1/x}$ is positive and ridiculously close to $0$. The more interesting limit is the limit as $x\to 0^+$. Depending on taste, you can say that it does not exist or is $\infty$.

Comment: Another question since I don't think I could wait another 20 minutes to figure out the answer to this:

Comment: Put $\frac{1}{x}= y $ , and  look at $\frac{ e^y}{ y^3}, y\rightarrow \infty $

Comment: Your pending question got cut off, probably you pressed the Enter key.

Comment: lim t->infinity  [sin (1/t)] / (lnt)    I know when you plug in infinity you get 0/infinity ....how do I know if I should keep on going (rewriting) in this case. Because my teacher taught us that if we get the forms (infinity times zero, 1^infinity, infinity-infinity, infinity^0, 0^0, THEN we could rewrite to try to get the indeterminate forms of 0/0 or infinity/infinity so that we could actually apply lhopitals. In this case, however, I got 0/infinity.....so I'm not sure what I would do after that since I've never seen this indeterminate form before and it's not part of the list .............

Comment: would I even be able to use lhopitals?

Comment: (yes i did press the enter key..I always do that :/ )

Comment: Oh wait a second...I think I just answered my own question. 0/infinity is not an indeterminate form so then it's just zero, right?

Comment: $\sin(1/t)$ goes to $0$, while $\ln t$ blows up in a leisurely way. So the limit is $0$. One cannot use L'Hospital's Rule. By the way, same thing with $\frac{\sin t}{\ln t}$ since $\sin t$ stays between $0$ and $1$ in absolute value, so the $\ln t$ at the bottom ultimately crushes it.

Comment: Oh okay, thank you again André Nicolas.  Limits are definitely not my forte. Almost every problem I come across that involves limits and indeterminate forms...I have questions. By the way, since 0/infinity is not indeterminate (according to this worksheet he gave us), does that mean it's just 0?

Comment: I don't like the notation $0/0$ or $0/\infty$. But yes, it "is" (shudder!) $0$.

Comment: I won't even bother to ask why that is. Math is weird. Thank you André Nicolas.

Comment: You are welcome. Math is perhaps weird, but it is less weird than other subjects.

Answer (score 1):

There is another way to compute this limit. We can write
$$
\lim_{x\to 0^-}x^3e^{\frac{1}{x}}=\lim_{x\to 0^-}x^3\lim_{x\to 0^-}e^{\frac{1}{x}}.
$$
The first limit quite obviously goes to zero. For the second limit, let $\epsilon>0$ and $\delta=\frac{1}{\epsilon}.$ Then
$$
-\frac{1}{x}<-\frac{1}{1/\epsilon}=-\epsilon~\forall ~x\in (-\delta,0).
$$ 
Since we can choose $\epsilon$ arbitrarily large, conclude
$$
\lim_{x\to 0^-}\frac{1}{x}=-\infty .
$$
Hence we have 
$$
0\times e^{-\infty}=0.
$$